# How can i clean up QFormLayout?

Tags: python, layout, pyside

I want to change `QFormLayout` content dynamically. I can with layout's `takeAt()` method.
But `rowCount()` is holding its number, every time I rebuild the form, it returns an increasing number...

How can I make `rowCount` returning `0` when the layout items are clean?

```
# coding: utf-8
import sys, os

from PySide.QtGui import *

class TestWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(TestWindow, self).__init__()

        self.formArea = QWidget(self)
        self.formlayout = QFormLayout()
        self.formArea.setLayout(self.formlayout)

        rebuildButton = QPushButton(self)
        rebuildButton.setText('Rebuild')
        rebuildButton.clicked.connect(self.rebuildForm)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)
        layout.addWidget(self.formArea)
        layout.addWidget(rebuildButton)

        self.rebuildForm()

    def rebuildForm(self):
        # clear all items in formlayout
        print('##### start cleaning #####')
        while self.formlayout.count() :
            print('current count = %d / rowCount = %d' % (self.formlayout.count(),
                                                          self.formlayout.rowCount()))
            item = self.formlayout.takeAt(0)
            del(item)

        # build forms
        for i in xrange(3) :
            lineEdit = QLineEdit(self.formArea)
            self.formlayout.addRow('row %d' % i, lineEdit)

if __name__ == '__main__' :
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = TestWindow()
    win.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Here is its output, pushing call `rebuildForm` 3 times.

```
##### start cleaning #####
##### start cleaning #####
current count = 6 / rowCount = 3
current count = 5 / rowCount = 3
current count = 4 / rowCount = 3
current count = 3 / rowCount = 3
current count = 2 / rowCount = 3
current count = 1 / rowCount = 3
##### start cleaning #####
current count = 6 / rowCount = 6
current count = 5 / rowCount = 6
current count = 4 / rowCount = 6
current count = 3 / rowCount = 6
current count = 2 / rowCount = 6
current count = 1 / rowCount = 6
##### start cleaning #####
current count = 6 / rowCount = 9
current count = 5 / rowCount = 9
current count = 4 / rowCount = 9
current count = 3 / rowCount = 9
current count = 2 / rowCount = 9
current count = 1 / rowCount = 9
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't. It's an implementation detail of some layouts (`QGridLayout` is another), that the number of *logical* rows never decreases. That is why there is no `removeRow()` method. So, rather than trying to delete all the rows, just re-use the ones that are already there (and add more whenever necessary).

You could also just ignore the empty rows, and use methods like [getWidgetPosition](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qformlayout.html#getWidgetPosition), so that you always work with *logical* rows, rather than the *visual* rows.